# Is there a word, similar to "catachresis" meaning to use a word for its general understanding rather than by its strictly literal definition?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm wondering if there is a word/term or, even if not a single-word, just an accepted phrase that represents the idea of not necessarily misusing a word, but using it as its intended meaning, with a slightly different nuance?

So, to explain, an example of a catachresis could be using *mitigate* when the speaker meant *militate*. In that example, the user is not conveying what they want to convey, they're using a word with a completely different meaning than what they want.

An example of the word I am looking for, could be using *terroir* when talking about things other than wine.

The definition of terroir

> The complete natural environment in which a particular wine is produced, including factors such as the soil, topography, and climate.

specifically calls out "wine" as being the thing in focus, meaning that these sentences:

> The terroir of Hatch, New Mexico, means that only Anaheim peppers grown there can be considered authentic "Hatch Peppers."

> The Florida Keys' warm, abundant, coastal rains, and alkaline soil contribute to the terroir of Key Limes, which leads to a bigger fruit than when grown elsewhere.

are not abiding to the literal definition of the word *terroir*, but they are using the word in a way that a reader could very easily understand what is meant because only one small nuance has changed (it's not about wine), and the general meaning of the word stays the same.

To supply an example where this term could come into play:

> John _____ (past-tense verb) the word "terroir" because he used it when talking about peppers instead of wines.

> John's _____ (noun) of the word "terroir" when talking about Hatch Peppers was amusing to me as I had recently done the same thing with Key Limes.

Comment: Thinking impressionistically, maybe improvised and improvisation?

Comment: 'catachresis' is essentially 'using a word wrong', so I don't think you mean that. The concept you are describing seems to be a 'broad use' or a 'metaphor' or 'figuratively'.

Comment: terroir is not about wine per se. It is applied to wine but could by extension apply to other agricultural products/produce.

Comment: The complement of 'literal' is 'figurative'.

Comment: @Lambie Perhaps it's a question of who is the best authority when it comes to literal definitions and for my question terroir wasn't the best example, but OED, Merriam Webster and other dictionaries I looked at specifically called out either "wine" or "wine grapes."

Comment: @Mitch That's very true and a good point; I guess I'm wondering if a word/concept exists that more specifically points to the act of changing only a small part of the literal definition and leaving the rest of it the same, not necessarily using the word in an entirely figurative manner.

Comment: No worries. Speaking of French, a friend of mine there called using the wrong word "une faute de concierge" because in rich neighborhoods the building supers try to ape the residents they "take care of".

Comment: Frankly, this kind of mistake is either a lapsus or just plain ignorance.

Comment: Perhaps a [**misnomer**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/misnomer) although that word too is sometimes used incorrectly, and it does not fit the blanks.

Comment: I believe you are looking for [_semantic broadening, generalization, expansion, or extension_](https://www.thoughtco.com/broadening-semantic-generalization-1689181).

Comment: As a verb, _to extend_. _OED_ definition: "To widen the range, scope, area of application of (a law, operation, dominion, state of things, etc.); to enlarge the scope or meaning of (a word)."